# Typescript callback params depends on other option params

Tags: typescript

I have types like this;

```
type Admin = {
  propertyA: string;
  propertyB: string;
}

type User = {
  propertyC: string;
  propertyE: string;
}

interface AuthProviderProps {
  userType: 'user' | 'admin';
  onUserLoggedIn: (user) => void;
}
```

How can i pass right user type to `onUserLoggedIn` depends on `userType`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to generic solution by @AlexWayne, you can use a discriminated union.

I prefer it this solution over generics as you dont need to repeat type of the of the user twice (one in generic param, second in userType field)

```
interface AuthProviderPropsUser {
  userType: 'user';
  onUserLoggedIn: (user: User) => void;
}

interface AuthProviderPropsAdmin {
  userType: 'admin';
  onUserLoggedIn: (user: Admin) => void;
}

type AuthProviderProps = AuthProviderPropsUser | AuthProviderPropsAdmin;

const x: AuthProviderProps = {
    userType: 'user',
    onUserLoggedIn: (user) => {
      console.log(user.propertyC); // OK
      console.log(user.propertyA); // Error Property 'propertyA' does not exist on type 'User'. Did you mean 'propertyC'?
    },
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJgWwJYDsoF4oG8BQUpgBOA9pIaDAFxQDOwhqA5gNx4ElmgBC1dDKLHAF8cOUJCgBVGhEIZsbIqVmgAwr3pNW%20JZxABRDf0EicqYLIBmAQwDG0GAFdgACwAKJAG5I4sj6RppWQV8RxlCABVwCGoAcjDZWO0oYhQgwgAZYkZGCDgASRRqAAoEwmp0gEoMAD4oT2IfVlNzKzsHZ3cvHz8OGnhkNFxQ8KjIOOtEVCS2VPSsnLzCkrLqAdRq9DqGpuFRcQ7Xf29fQn8wGnknI%207T88DwqAAfWE7jnrO%209ZRWHFtUuhQAAeazet16AXkw3wUDKYxiUHi4ViABo2Pg5uEFrkCkUoKVwps6tCYVB-igaMQADYQAB0VOyBNktN0KhAqkqzCgAHpuVAAPIAaXRMPJlJp9MZZRZHDZME5PL5%20kIJDk5zZiNZ5BAMFiUDgxAglxQxGAUAgQKQgNSUAOiPSsVpUAAIj4oCBiI4oAgINY0LEtWpYgB%20EVCNFCIA)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) here to capture a type, and then reference it elsewhere.

```
interface AuthProviderProps<T extends 'user' | 'admin'> {
  userType: T;
  onUserLoggedIn: (user: T) => void;
}
```

When you would use like so:

```
const userProps: AuthProviderProps<'admin'> = {
  userType: 'admin',
  onUserLoggedIn(user) { // typescript knows user is of type 'admin' here
    console.log(user)
  }
}
```